# Is there are map function for mapping array list in angular?

Tags: angular, arraylist, array-map

I have array list like this,

[image]

It's randomly come data as a same template whatever its keys its same in all arrays in the array list.
I want to show this array list in the table like this,

[image]

And always change the keys of arrays in the list. Sometimes its have 2 keys like phone, address. Sometimes its have 3 keys like name, phone, address.

[image]

So are there any function for mapping data like this in angular?

Comment: I think your question is not clear, `array.map` does the job for you, but is that not what you want?

Comment: can you give sample code for my example using array.map ?

Comment: are you looking to map the array in a table using angular or you're looking for something else?

Comment: yeah I looking for map my array list to table in angular.

Comment: here is how you do it using angular material `https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview`

Answer (score 0):

Assign your array to a variable and loop that variable in html to create a table

```
 <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Address</th>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of array">
        <td>{{item?.name || 'no name'}}</td>
        <td>{{item?.phone}}</td>
        <td>{{item?.address}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But Its always not the same keys in the array. Some array list have another group of keys. :/

Comment: could you post that array ?

Comment: I posted it below

Comment: updated my answer based on your feedback.you can just leave empty or add a string for empty keys

Answer (score 0):

Use the safe navigation operator [`?.`](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths). It guards against `null` and `undefined` values in property paths. It can also be chained if you have a tree like structure `item?.name?.firstname`.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of arr">
  <p>{{item?.name || '&nbsp;'}}</p>
  <p>{{item?.phone || '&nbsp;'}}</p>
  <p>{{item?.address || '&nbsp;'}}</p>
</div>
```

**Update**

If you do not know the keys, then it is not really ideal to display the value in the table. Nevertheless, you could use the [`keyvalue`](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) pipe. However you do not know which value you are handling at any moment.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of arr">
  <div *ngFor="let data of item | keyvalue">
    {{data.value}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1atkhq)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But sometimes its have totally different keys :(

Comment: Could you please update your question with any of such different keys? And do you have to a list of all the possibe key names?

Comment: No, I haven't any possible key name list. Data come from totally different forms. Each one form has one array list. So form fields change so that keys also change from each array list

Comment: Please check my update. But I should note displaying object data without knowing their keys isn't ideal.